# Accept multiple changes in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013, tracking

Can I accept all tracked changes in a specific area (where I dragged)?

I'm using MS Word 2013 for Windows.

Answer (score 13):

Yes. Select an area and click `Accept` in the `Review` tab. This will accept all changes in the selected area.

Comment: no it won't, at least not with tables in word 2021, 365 version...

Comment: Does not work for me.
Word / MS Office Standard, 14.0.7015.1000 (32-Bit)